# Asp.net MVC 4 with entity framework + repository +angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas, n-tier-architecture

I am creating web application from scratch using Visual studio 2012,  Asp.net MVC 4 + entity framework (database first approach) + angular.js + sql-server 2012. I am also thinking of using repository layer.
It is medium size rapid deveoplment project. It is database oriented application doing CRUD operation with around 20-25 screens.

I have starting creating solution ( framework) for it but not sure where to keep entity framework. 
Is anyone has readymade solution which can be reused for this application?

Also is it advisable to use angular.js or jquery since it is rapid development project... i have heard angular.js have several readymade function for control binding whereas in jquery we have to write lot of code..... please advise

Comment: EF and repository pattern are not mutually exclusive. Repositories decouple the data/ORM framework from the application... But it's very common to see EF used inside a repository. As for angular, it's a great framework if you are building a single page app. If you are building plain MVC CRUD pages with postbacks, angular might actually get in your way.

Comment: you might check [this](https://github.com/MarlabsInc/webapi-angularjs-spa) out